# Memory leaks on Firefox addons

Tags: javascript, firefox, memory-leaks, firefox-addon

I have an addon, which is pretty big, and I need to understand some things...

- What causes memory leak on a Firefox addon?
- How can I find what is causing the leak?
- How can I fix the leak?

The addon adds some elements on the page, request parts of the page and update the DOM. The memory increases each time I reload the page, and the memory is not released even after closing the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2490/) which can catch some types of memory leaks. There is more documentation on debugging leaks [here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Performance:Leak_Tools), but it's a little hard to read.

Comment: Outdated.  Doesn't work with Firefox versions newer than 4.0.